# How to fix "ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [395, 1]" error in python

Tags: python, linear-regression

i'm new to python and i'm trying to learn Machine Learning. then i encounter this kind of error. What should i do?

```
predict = "G3"

X = np.array(data.drop([predict], 1))
y = np.array([predict]) 
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1)
```

Comment: Apparently X and y do not have consistent shapes. I suspect that the mistake is in y = np.array([predict]). Is "predict" a string with a column name or a list of values? Have you tried printing X.shape and y.shape before splitting (for debugging purposes). Your example doesn't really have enough information to debug, but I assume you meant y = data[predict], where predict is the name of the target variable

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to help you, we will need to be able to reproduce your error. So you need to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i tried printing the y.shape and the output is 1.

Comment: the "predict" is a list of value